# VB.Net TCP/IP Client-Server connectivity

Tags: vb.net, tcp

When the Client side of a Software fails to successfully recognize the Port Address of a Server System, is there a way to make the Port Address recognition process, dynamic, so you needn't have to specify such, as in the case of User Datagram Protocol(UDP); that is a connectionless-based network communication style?
Thanks..

Comment: Okay, I don't know about others here, but I don't understand anything of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Alright, not to bother really..just wondering how to get the Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise ed., Setup and Deployment kit. Any help, would be appreciated.. Thanks..